# How to query the order result in this table structure in MYSQL/ SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently work on the e-shopping cart project and need to record the tranasaction

The structure is like this:

```
order
------
id
order_id
* member_id

member
------
id
member_id

status
--------
id
description 
* order_id
create_date
```

So, the status is to store the order change status, e.g. when the order is received , then I add the order , and add the status with the description 100 <== I define and hardcode it . And if the order is deliver, then I will insert one more status 200 <== also is I define.

Then , the problem is , how to query the result like this?

```
 (Desc) create_date order_id member-id status_description

e.g. 
      2014 06 13 05:00:00 #11111 #12345 order_receive
      2014 06 13 03:00:00 #15555 #12222 order_deliver
```

**Notice**  e.g. I store the status time whenever the order update. So there should be a several status of the order, and the result should contain the latest status **only** , so I need to get the max (create_date). How to structure the query in this scenario?

I have thought about it but it is not in one query, I wonder are there any way to create it in one query? Thanks

**Update**

My attempt query is like this

1. select order_id from status group by order_id order by create_date
2. In PHP , for each order_id, select * from order where order_id = that id and join the member table

Comment: Please update your question with the attempts you've made at writing the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT src.max_date,
       src.order_id,
       src.member_id,
       CASE
           WHEN s1.description = 100 THEN 'order_receive'
           WHEN s1.description = 200 THEN 'order_deliver'
       END AS status_description FROM
  (SELECT MAX(s.create_date) max_date, s.order_id , o.member_id
   FROM status s
   JOIN `order` o ON o.order_id = s.order_id
   GROUP BY s.order_id, o.member_id) src
JOIN status s1 ON s1.create_date = src.max_date;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83cc6/1)

Comment: Thanks, and should be join order o?

Comment: Retry this with demo :)

Comment: Thanks but it seems the description is not align with the create_date?

Comment: that means the query only return the description that is "group by" but not the description of the max (create date)

Comment: If I understand your business correctly, "greater the description, then greater the create_date". So the MAX would be a shortcut solution.

Comment: refer to the demo you created , the first row create date is correct (October, 03 2013 06:00:00+0000) but the description is 100 instead of 200

Comment: check again :) must be `200` to be `order_delivered`

Comment: the description is align with the create date , it can be something like 100 (pending) => 101 (order fail, retry) => 100 (pending) so I afraid the MAX (description) is not the solution